# Reteun obj in hashmap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a model which is named `PeerModel` is written with JSON. In another class, I set this model as a key of a HashMap.

```
Map<PeerModel,Boolean> peers = new HashMap<>();
```

now I have a method and I need to check if the value is false, return the model(which is key of the HashMap).
This is the code but it returns null.

```
public PeerModel getUnusedPeer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < peers.size(); i++)
        if (peers.containsValue(i) == false)

            return new PeerModel();
}
```

Comment: Please add the rest of the code, where you add items to the peers map.  I'm guessing your map is empty, so will always return null.

Comment: Your map values are of type `Boolean`, and you're calling `containsValue` with an `int` (which is then autoboxed to `Integer`). Imagine having a chest that you know only contains marbles, and then rummaging through the chest to see if there's a fish inside.

I'm pretty sure you're using the wrong datastructure for whatever it is you want to do

Comment: Also, you don't "[...] return the model(which is key of the HashMap)", instead you return a new model that is not linked to the map in any way.

Comment: Another minor thing:  The code you posted for `getUnusedPeer()` should not return `null`, this code should fail to compile with an error message "Control reaches end of non-void function" or similar.

Comment: I have a JSON file to define the peers as an static {
  "peers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "peer01",
      "ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 1234
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "peer01",
      "ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 1235
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that there is only one false value in the map (Since your method return only one PeerModel object), you can use something like :

```java
Optional<PeerModel> optional = peers.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> !e.getValue())
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
  .findFirst();
```

Comment: Thanks, Florian, can you please explain a bit about this code? and what should I write for the return of the method?  
The idea is to search in the hashmap and find the keys(which is an Object) whose value is false.

Comment: @venuskiani you can just return the `optional` - that way, the caller will have to deal with the case when no unused peer is found. Or you return `null` for the empty case, but that means if the caller forgets to deal with this case, a `NullPointerException` will likely be thrown.

Comment: when i use return optional , i get this error "java: incompatible types: java.util.Optional<model.PeerModel> cannot be converted to model.PeerModel" .  But is correct if I write return optional.get() ?

Comment: yes, of course - you need to adjust your method signature, and where the return value is used, you need to decide what to do with it with one of the methods on [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), e.g. [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) to specify a default value.

Comment: Note that this code return an Optional<PeerModel> using `findFirst()` method. It means if you have more than one entry in your map with a false value, it will only return the first one. If you want to return all the keys whose value is false, adapt the code above to return a List<PeerModel> (you can do it with `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `.findFirst()`

Comment: right, I have access to all keys. But when I use your suggested solution I received an error when I want to access the port.    socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", Math.toIntExact(config.getUnusedPeer().getPort())))  the erroe is related to the end of the code which written getport()

Comment: I guess `getPort()` is a getter of the class PeerModel : `.findFirst()` return an Optional, so it should be `config.getUnusedPeer().get().getPort()` (The get method on the optional can return null if the filter return an empty stream)